# Pandas: sep in read_csv doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I try to `read_csv`

```
e29bea24f74b7fb26cb9c14ef8c3b10b,ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33849562,2016-03-27 01:08:43,16,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
e29bea24f74b7fb26cb9c14ef8c3b10b,ozon.ru/context/detail/id/24744347,2016-03-27 01:08:59,44,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
e29bea24f74b7fb26cb9c14ef8c3b10b,ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135168438,2016-03-27 01:11:39,6,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
e29bea24f74b7fb26cb9c14ef8c3b10b,ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33290689,2016-03-27 01:12:37,8,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
e29bea24f74b7fb26cb9c14ef8c3b10b,ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31642544,2016-03-27 01:13:07,14,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
1cf378e0ba824651d9d80b076514bfe7,citilink.ru,2016-03-27 01:54:22,12,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
1cf378e0ba824651d9d80b076514bfe7,citilink.ru/catalog/computers_and_notebooks/net_equipment/netcards/90520,2016-03-27 01:55:26,20,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
1cf378e0ba824651d9d80b076514bfe7,citilink.ru/catalog/computers_and_notebooks/net_equipment/netcards/896835,2016-03-27 01:55:58,10,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
1cf378e0ba824651d9d80b076514bfe7,citilink.ru/catalog/computers_and_notebooks/net_equipment/netcards/896840,2016-03-27 01:57:48,52,,Р С›Р Р…Р В»Р В°Р в„–Р Р…-Р СР В°Р С–Р В°Р В·Р С‘Р Р…
```

I use

```
names = ['ID', 'url', 'date', 'duration', 'request', 'category']
df = pd.read_csv('pv-lena11.csv', sep=",", header=None, names=names)
```

but it doesn't separate that.

Comment: It works fine for me - what problems did you have?

Comment: @MaxU I get column ID with all data, but other columns are NaN

Comment: @PetrPetrov how dit you create the file? I know Excel sometimes uses `;` even though it saves it as an csv.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my laptop.

What's your pandas version? Is your file encoded as UTF-8? Can you try if this work?

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'pv-lena11.csv', sep=',', header=None, names=names, 
    quoting=0, encoding='utf8')
```